# Django full text search using SearchHeadline for multiple fields

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-annotate, django-searchvector

While using django full text search can we use **SearchHeadline** for mutiple field as of now if only takes one field to annotate headline.

```
search_vector = SearchVector('title', 'body')
search_query = SearchQuery(search_post)
search_headline = SearchHeadline('body', search_query)
questions = posts.annotate(search=search_vector, rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)).annotate(headline=search_headline).filter(rank__gt=0.0001).order_by('-rank')
```

I use `{{ post.headline|safe}}`to view this in my django template.

Is there any way i can use another SearchHeadline where i can headline `'title'` field which is used in search vector.

I tried annotate more than 2 times it over rides the previous headline.

Is there any solution which can be implemented?